# Invoke method similar to WCF invoker?

Tags: c#, json, wcf

Some strong typed classes:

```
public class A 
{
    public C Process(B b)
    { 
        return new C()
        {
            Output = b.Property + " bar!"
        };
    }
}

public class B
{
    public string Property {get;set;}
}

public class C
{
    public string Output {get;set;}
}
```

Input as JSON string:

```
string input = "{\"Property\":\"foo\"}";
```

And what I want is if I have instance of A as object, I want to invoke this JSON and retrieve object output:

```
object instanceOfA = new A();

object result = instanceOfA.GetType().GetMethod("Process").Invoke(instanceOfA, new []{ /*json here?*/});
```

So, it is basically similar to some JavaScript call on some plain argument.

Answer (score 1):

What about changing the method signature for the 'Process' method to take a string as input instead and attempting to de-serialize the input to the type you want? So something like this:

```
string input = "{\"Property\":\"foo\"}";
object instanceOfA = new A();
object result = instanceOfA.GetType().GetMethod("Process").Invoke(instanceOfA, new object[]{ input });

public class A
{
    public C Process(string input)
    {
        var b = (B) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(input, typeof(B));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.Property))
        {
            return new C()
            {
                Output = b.Property + " bar!"
            };
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class B
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public string Output { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This won't do. I write plugin, and don't want to deserialze "something" every time I write new plugin. Better to delegate this task to some upper layer which will do this all the time.

Comment: OK. I'm not sure then that I fully understand what you need. If you are doing the serialization and de-seriaization at an upper level and the "something" can vary will you still not need to return different object types from the Process method? If so you could use an interface either as the method param or alternatively use a string as both the input and output of the method.

Comment: I can't use string as input to plugin. Draw analogy with WCF contracts - you work with strong typed entities and you don't even know how they represented - as string, as byte array or whatever.

Comment: The comparison I am thinking of is a custom model binder in MVC where you could implement another layer on top to route the calls to the plugin through and bind the Json to entities there first. But this probably isn't what you need. Sorry I couldn't be more help

Comment: I already found partial solution. I will post it a bit later.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was simply solved with Newtonsoft.Json features:

```
public class JsonInvoker
{
    private readonly MethodInfo _methodInfo;
    private readonly Type _paramType;
    private readonly JsonSerializerSettings _settings;
    public JsonInvoker(Type instanceType, string methodName)
    {
        _methodInfo = instanceType.GetMethod(methodName);
        _paramType = _methodInfo.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
        _settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new RequireObjectPropertiesContractResolver(),
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error
        };
    }

    public object Invoke(object instance, string json)
    {
        var input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, _paramType, _settings);
        var output = _methodInfo.Invoke(instance, new[] { input });
        return output;
    }

    private class RequireObjectPropertiesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
        {
            var contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
            contract.ItemRequired = Required.AllowNull;
            return contract;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can invoke my method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object plugin = new A();
        string json = "{\"Property\":\"foo\"}";
        var invoker = new JsonInvoker(plugin.GetType(), "Process");
        //here I call invoker with simple string.
        var output = invoker.Invoke(plugin, json);

    }
}



public class A
{
    public C Process(B input)
    {
        return new C
               {
                   Property = input.Property + " bar"
               };
    }
}

public class C
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}
```